# Why Not Train ML on Larger Clusters for Shorter Intervals?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cluster-computing, google-cloud-ml

[TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) and [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/aws_distributed_training_tutorial.html) support distributed training strategies for massive data parallelism. GCP's [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) suggests that their per-GPU costs scale efficiently w/ large clusters.

With this in mind, why do those who utilize GCP (or cloud platforms in general) for ML training elect to train using fewer GPUs for longer times, if the net expenditure would be the same or similar?

I'm assuming I'm missing some crucial information or neglecting some scaling costs. GCP's AI Platform training costs significantly more than its Compute Engine ($1.21 vs $0.45 per K80), but seems to scale similarly well.

EDIT:
Per comments, I probably made a mistake when comparing Compute Engine and AI Platform prices w/ the pricing tool.

Comment: Training speed will not scale linearly when you are adding more GPUs. Training time is another factor to consider. BTW, the K80 pricing is the same on AI Platform and Compute Engine, which is $0.45 /GPU / hour. https://cloud.google.com/compute/gpus-pricing#gpus

Comment: Thanks! I wonder where I introduced a pricing disparity using the pricing tool... maybe the AI Platform comes w/ additional costs. @GuoqingXu is the nonlinear scaling due to worker-worker communication via something like all-reduce operations?

Comment: Maybe you included the cost of CPUs and disk in one calculation but didn't in another one.

Comment: What you mentioned is one of the potential reasons. For example, the batch size will also impact convergence.